# Stuck/rusted/frozen lug nuts, unable to get to a store

Tags: lug-nut

I blew a tire leaving my house yesterday(I mean BLEW it to shreds) and I have a spare/donut but can't get the lug nuts to budge to get the blown tire off.

They are somewhat rusted and it is also in the single digits here, so I'm thinking they could possibly be frozen. I have a somewhat powerful Kobalt 1/2 inch impact that has failed to do anything as well. I have a can of PV Blaster but for some reason the nozzle is refusing to work, which is odd because it was fine last I used it and it's been stored in a warm room.

My biggest problem is, due to my location, it would be really difficult to get to any sort of store other than one gas station that is a few miles away and I could walk to. I do not have a heat gun or anything of that sort.

If anyone could have additional tips for me it would be highly appreciated. I'm pretty rurally located and need to find a household solution for this. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it you don't have a lug wrench of any sort? Sometimes constant torque works better on the lug nuts than does an impact. If you can set a lug wrench parallel with the ground, you can stand on it (bounce on it even) to get more torque applied to the lug.

Comment: When using a lug wrench - very good quality and an extension bar, apply the force by pulling up on the bar and use your leg muscles to provide the force - I have sheared big wheel studs as per Landrover like this but I'm 18 stone and 6'3".. Oh and keep your back straight... You can apply more force than just bouncing on it...

Comment: Oh, one last point if the nut does come unstuck make sure you don't hit two others with the end of the bar!!

Comment: If you cannot get a single nut to budge, I am wondering if you are turning it the proper direction. Some vehicles have a left-hand thread.

Comment: left hand thread on left hand side...

Comment: Penetrating oil and a long cheater bar on the lug wrench . Something will move. Very, very last resort, dremel tool with cut off discs.

Comment: A piece of steel pipe on the end of a lug works pretty well too. Keep at it, they'll budge.

Answer (score 1):

Take the car jack and place it under the lug nut wrench.  Use the jack to break it free.